K-folds cross validation in multi-GPU parallelization setup using Pytorch DDP
In a deep learning project which I am using use k-fold cross validation. I want to parallelize it to use multiple GPUs using pytorch's DDP strategy. I could not find a resource already doing this. I'm guessing it is because it might not be efficient. But I wanted to ask here to see if anyone has idea how we can do that.
I have tried DDP on 1-fold cross-validation, but interested in trying K-folds cross validation on multi-GPU training scenario.
